# How to implement an enum with specific values for its members?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I could be going about this all wrong, and it could be that an enum does is not a good way to solve this problem, but I am really not sure where to go with it otherwise.

Basically, I have non-sequential codes that correspond to certain strings. For example,

```
9 = "Enter"
10 = "Right"
15 = "Left"
17 = "Down"
```

And so on. I currently have this implemented with a large set of definitions:

```
#define ENTER_INDEX 0
#define RIGHT_INDEX 1
```

That is used to index into a char* array:

```
char* array[] = { "Enter", "Right" };
```

And when I receive information regarding which code was received, I then print the strings with a huge `switch`-case.

Any ideas on how to do this more efficiently? Is an `enum` a good approach?

Comment: enum can be used for non sequential numbers. that is not what you mean by enum in your question?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can use an `enum`, but that won't help you associate the names with the numerical values.

The problem is that you can't declare an enum and a string "in parallel" from the same source code characters, without using trickery such as [X macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro). Even then you probably won't solve the requirement for different casing which your code shows. Which you might want to avoid, because obfuscation.

The `enum` would be just:

```
typedef enum {
  ID_ENTER = 9,
  ID_RIGHT = 10,
  ID_LEFT = 15,
  ID_DOWN = 17
} Id;
```

I would then use C99's fantastic support for explicit indexes in array initializers to declare an array of strings indexed by an `Id`:

```
static const char *id_names[] = {
  [ID_ENTER] = "Enter",
  [ID_RIGHT] = "Right",
  /* add more */
};
```

Note that the above is independent of the order, since each element initializer has an explicit index. This makes it very robust.

You can of course use a macro to cut down on the repetition, but that will make an all-caps string array:

```
#define DECL_ID(i)  [ID_ ## i] = #i
static const char *id_names2[] = {
  DECL_ID(ENTER), DECL_ID(RIGHT), /* add more */
};
```

Comment: Will your id_names array contain only 2 elements in this case, or 10 (because ID_RIGHT = 10) with 8 unused?

Comment: @sherrellbc It will be 11 (0 through 10), otherwise the indexing wouldn't work. It's still a "hard-core" C array, not a dictionary or something.

Comment: @unwind +1. Why `static` storage class for `id_names` array? Also, will the remaining indices of the array be initialized to `NULL`?

Comment: @ajay Since it's a global variable it sometimes makes sense to make it `static` to isolate it to the current translation unit. And yes, I think the remaining indexes will be initialized to 0, which in pointer context is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

To implement an enum with specific values for its members can be done by

```
 enum options_en
{
     Enter=9,
     Right=10,
     Left=15,
     Down=17,
     Default=0;
} ;
```

then you can declare a variable which can take only values defined in the enumerated type

```
options_en  opt_val = Default;
```

For exploring more information about your question , refer this link, Found it very useful and is relevent to your question

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/enum.html

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary or hash table can be used. In c++ stl libraries I don't recall the name of the collection but in short y.  use dictionaries/hashtables with generics.

So in your case you fill up the dictionary with key value pairs and when your later use the collection you can get a value using your key.

So it gets rid of switch statements and enums and will allow you to map any two types. Here is pseudo code

Value = dictionary[key]

So if key is 0 then the value will be set to Enter based on your example.

In short lookup examples for c++ and dictionary as I am answering from mobile phone and could not direct you to the exact collection name.

Comment: I would use what's already out there unless you don't want to use stl or are programming on an embedded platform where c++ stl is not available. I haven't used stl in years and don't know if it is available in your environment and platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a map during initialization:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct { int code; const char *str; } key_info;
key_info keys[] = {
    {9, "Enter"}, {10, "Right"}, {15, "Left"}, {-1, NULL}
};

#define MAX_KEY_CODE 15
size_t keymap[MAX_KEY_CODE + 1];

int main ( ) {  
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; keys[i].str; i++) {
        keymap[keys[i].code] = i;
    }
    printf("%s\n", keys[keymap[10]].str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A huge switch is not a bad solution. The question is why do you need an extra array of names. Why don't you return directly string literals from the switch?

```
char *name(int code) {
  switch (code) {
  case 9:  return("Enter");
  case 10: return("Right");
  case 15: return("Left");
  ...
  }
}
```